# Why is orangutan meat not good to eat?

Tags: ethics, animal-welfare, practical-ethics

Many of us, even slightly familiar with ethics, know about [Tom Regan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tom_Regan) and his quest of establishing animal rights with us humans.  According to him, vegetarianism is a moral obligation of all people, because animals suffer and feel pain, thus they need our protection from being eaten, starved, used in scientific experiments or abused.

I agree with him... But where on the evolutionary 'tree of life' do we draw the line of what things to eat and what not to eat? Certainly all plants are fine because they lack a nervous system, but what animals deserve our protection and which ones, if any, do not?  Certainly eating members of one's own species is out of line (I hear the forearm is the best part), but so is killing and consuming members of the other great apes.

Comment: The question right now can be pulled in lots of directions: are you looking for how Tom Regan justifies his argument? Counterarguments? Is there anything you've looked at trying to set up a limiting principle for which animals are safe to eat?

Comment: James, I mean not what animals are "safe" to eat, rather, what animals, if any, are "ethical" to eat.  I agree with Regan--animals, even the great white shark, is a brother of ourselves.  Because -- Darwin is right!

Comment: Not sure how convincing the "Darwin is right" argument is. One could also say "Darwin is right, we're just animals, and animals eat members of the other species all the time."

Comment: A great white shark eats people from time to time, yet it's dumb to say they are evil because they know no better.  Us humans are different - I'm interested in knowing how I should behave, not only with other people, but also with the environment.  I just do not know to what end.

Comment: Your Q contains a good question: "where to draw the line of what things to eat and what not to eat??" But in your last paragraph, then, you go off tangent (the only objection to Regan's call is the fact that you do eat meat and …your age?). Would you mind deleting the last paragraph? It would improve your Q!

Comment: @DBK What a great idea!

Comment: Can you explain where the philosophical question is? There's a lot of potentially philosophical questions. Can you explain what sort of criteria you think are appropriate for drawing the line between what we should eat or not?

Comment: @virmaior I wish I knew where the line should be drawn as to what things we should or should not eat.  Our culture generally determines the kinds of foods we consume.  For example, in the west, cats are generally not eaten as they are considered "companion animals", but in other cultures, they eat cats all the time.  Regan, and I wish not to commit a straw man fallacy, insists (all?) animals need our protection as they are "subjects of a life", but certainly, crushing a horsefly that's about eat you is hardly anything to get ethically worked up about.

Comment: I would suggest adding the horsefly comment to your question. So then you are asking what sort of parameters we should use to draw the line? (I think a usual measure is degree of sentience [taken by many meat eater] or degree of biological similarity [taken by many lacto-ovo vegetarians]). But it would help to know what sort of moral framework we are working in (utilitiarian, deontic, virtue, etc)

Comment: @virmaior I'm not a utilitarian. Rather, Kant is right, duty is prior to happiness.  But what about happiness?  A life without happiness, where festivities and family does not matter, a life without humour and laughter, is a life not worth living?

Comment: "Is it true that cannibals won't eat clowns because they *taste funny*?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, I should warn that I'm not a vegetarian nor do I play one on TV. My wife is one however, and there are many different reasons people make this choice: ranging from not liking the taste of meat, health reasons, moral concerns (which could include religious reasons) about animal consumption or the treatment of animals who are later consumed, religious beliefs about animals (think cows in "Hinduism").

Most of those who believe it is wrong to eat animals for philosophical moral reasons are types of consequentialists who think it is wrong to inflict pain and suffering on animals, because wrong is the infliction of pain and suffering, and animal suffering is identical or sufficiently similar in kind to human suffering (this is the argument put forth by Peter Singer).

You could also come up with a conclusion that it is *in practice* wrong to eat meat due to the treatment of animals who are consumed for meat that is not universally opposed to eating meat. Here, a potential Kantian angle is that Kant thinks enjoying animal suffering is immoral because it encourages us to enjoy human suffering.

A separate route is the similarity route which argues that insofar as it is immoral to kill humans, it follows that it is immoral to kill something that differs from humans in only the most minute regard -- since whatever the basis is for killing humans being wrong, it's difficult to grasp how a minute change would completely eviscerate that. (This is a type of argument by analogy). This route could be rejected if you think **rationality** is the definition of why human life has worth but not price.

A further distinct avenue is to accept the Kantian premise that what makes our lives have worth is that we are rational -- and to show that many animals (say Dolphins) demonstrate a degree of rationality that means we should afford them this protection. This is the logic behind say the PETA lawsuit arguing that Seaworld is slavery because whales are people. It seems that Kant would accept such an argument since our rationality and humanity for  him refers not to our participation in the human biological species but insofar as we are rational creatures (thus, an alien on Kant's view would have humanity if it has rationality and empirical desires).

There's a separate thread somewhere on here about being vegetarian that might give you more to chew on.

Comment: But vegetarians need larger teeth, and they have to consume more.